# Send request to WordPress REST API

Tags: rest-api

I have a server (server 1) which send requests to another server (server 2) where WordPress is installed and I am using their (server 2) WP REST API.

The problem is that I can't create/send `wp-nonce` from server 1 to server 2, and I am getting the following response:

```
{
"code": "rest_not_logged_in",
"message": "You are not currently logged in.",
"data": {
    "status": 401
}
}
```

I know that is not easy to disable nonce for REST API, but what is the proper way to send requests from another server to the WP REST API ?

Comment: Are you trying to do this with AJAX?  Could be a cross domain issue.  Which you would need JSONP to do.

Comment: Nope, this is another server, which send requests when something happen on it (server 1 events)

Comment: No I mean are the servers on the same domain?  If they aren't you'll have to use CORS.  See Cross Domain REST Call using CORS - https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/cross-domain-rest-calls-using-cors/

Comment: What alternate [authentication method](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins) are you using to authenticate your requests? Since you are trying to authenticate from a remote server to WordPress you can't use the native cookie method.

Comment: They are on different domains, but now I am trying this plugin `rest-api-oauth1` (which is free) and on the server 1 - NodeJS - `Request` library with `OAuth 1.0a` library. I think, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Since your specific scenario is a remote application making a request to WordPress you'll need to explore [additional authentication methods available via plugins](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins) for the REST API. I won't make any specific recommendations since I don't know your use case in detail but I'm sure you will find one that works well.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your theme's functions.php file at the top.  This will allow you to use Cross Domain calls from your functions.php.

```
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```